# Unicode problem with Android

Tags: android, softkeys

I am using **Unicode** at the place of **ASCII** in Soft keyboard application,
bt i found some code like :

↑ - ↑ (up arrow) 
↓ - ↓ (down arrow) 
← - ← (left arrow) 
→ - → (right arrow) 
↵ - ↵ (down-left arrow) 
↨ - ↨ (up-down arrow with bottom line) ...and may be more

have problem,showing Rectangular/space.
Any one have list of Supported Unicode Char list for Android.

**Thank in Advance**

Comment: The problem is not clear... as least I failed to understand.
Can you post some screenshot what you see vis-a-vis what you expect?

I have worked with almost every popular language include RTL, Chinese, Korean, Japanese etc and their mapping in Unicode charset... may be of some help :)

Comment: Thnx Gaurav..
image at http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.9d13a29975.png
I set Unicode char in XML file at the place of ASCII..and when i press any key of soft keyboard it shows this type of blank box in appliaction text box.
pls reply

Answer (score 1):

Android supports all Unicode characters, but Android does not have the fonts needed to display proper glyphs for many of those characters

To display any characters properly your application needs to use a font that contains glyphs for those particular characters. If you try to display a character that has no glyph in the font being used, you will simply get the default box displayed.